# Why should I buy an apartment?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

What is the purpose of owning an apartment? What are the benefits to owning an apartment?

Comment: From what Lester tells you during mission briefings, you'll need an apartment to do "bigger jobs". Those could be the heists Rockstar promised. Also in the 10-garage-apartments there is a room with the world map, which could further indicate this. In the end I'm guessing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apartments also allow you to define a spawn location for when you start a new session.

Comment: As an aside to this, if you finish a job in a place far away from where you wish to be (you end up in Sandy Shores and want to be at Vespucci Beach for example), then by setting your spawn location to apartment and finding a new session you will be transported there, saving you the drive.

I am not sure if this is regarded as exploitative however and may not always be a time saver after loading times and leaving the apartment.

Answer (score 0):

[From GTA wiki](http://gta.wikia.com/Grand_Theft_Auto_Online)

> When a player purchases an apartment, they can invite other players to
>   come and visit them. When another player comes to visit, they will use
>   a door bell, which will be heard by the player who owns the apartment.
>   The player can then choose whether or not to let them. The player can
>   also use CCTV on their TV to check who is actually outside.